# Active Reports 6 - Chinese text in report changes font-family of the other fields in the report

Tags: .net, report, activereports

I am using Active Reports 6 for the reporting needs. I am facing some issue when Chinese text is displayed on the report. 
The font-family of the non-chinese text fields also gets changed in the report when Chinese text is displayed. Also some text overflows outside the boundary when Chinese text is displayed in the report. I am using Arial font-family in the report.

Please find the two snapshot of the same reports below. The second report with Chinese field gives weird output with different font-family and overflowing text.

Report snapshot with only English:
[image]

Report snapshot with English and Chinese:
[image]

Please help to resolve this issue.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

it will be difficult to help you out from here.  Can you please email the report document (rdf) to activereports.support@grapecity.com.  Also email the report(layout).  Do you have any runtime code?

http://helpcentral.componentone.com/NetHelp/ActiveReports6/arHOWSaveandLoadReportFiles.html